# Defining a line from an inequality

Tags: inequality, euclidean-geometry

So I am currently working on understanding a solution to a complex problem.
I am stuck with one of the things that are "logical jumps" that are described.

The author defines a Euclidean plane of $(p, v)$.

Then he states the following inequality which I undestand and agree with:

$P + t V − 4 ≤ a + t b ≤ P + t V$, where $(P, V)$ and $(a, b)$ are points on the plane and $t$ is time.

He then states that the abovementioned inequality defines an infinite strip of slope $(-1/t)$ and horizontal width $4$.

I tried graphing the inequality in Geogebra, but strange things happen and it only seems to work for $t=1$.

I would very much appreciate any help that could conclude in me understanding how the author came up with his conclusion regarding the "infinite strip of..."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a link to the original problem? It might help someone answer.

Comment: I have the link, I didn't post it because it is quite complicated. The problem:

A battleship of length 4 is moving along the real line in an unknown direction at a constant speed. It starts at an unknown position P, and is moving with speed V, but both of these are unknown real numbers. At every second you can shoot at some number on the real line; if you strike the ship the process ends successfully. Find a stategy that guarantees success in finite time.

the link to the solution : http://stanwagon.com/potw/current_solutions/s1164.html

My question is about papagraph 4 of the solution.